# OpenImageIOをソースからビルドしたい

Tags: ubuntu, build

https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenImageIO
このリポジトリのライブラリをソースコードからビルドしたいです。

なおリンク先には、任意で用意するライブラリがあるようですが、OpenImageIOをビルドできる最低限にしたいです。

**環境:**
Ubuntu 22.04
g++ 4.11.02
cmake 3.22.01
openEXR 2.7.5-1
libtiff-dev 4.3.0
libjpeg-dev 8c-2
libboost-all 1.74.0
fmtlib (gitでcloneしてmakeしましたが、インストールできていないかもしれません)

##### 追記

makeをするとstd:filesystemといった部分にエラーが出てきます。コンパイルはc++17でやっています。これを直したいです。

vcpkgについては、`vcpkg install openimageio`としたところBUILD FAILUREとエラーが出てしまいました。

git clone してきたOpenImageIOのディレクトリで以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
make ENABLE_Qt5=0 ENABLE_Python=0 ENABLE_pybind11=0 ENABLE_Numpy=0 ENABLE_LibRaw=0 ENABLE_FFmpeg=0 ENABLE_OpenJpeg=0 ENABLE_OpenVDB=0 ENABLE_TBB=0 ENABLE_OpenCV=0 ENABLE_giflib=0 ENABLE_l
ibheif=0 ENABLE_DCMTK=0 ENABLE_WebP=0 ENABLE_OpenColorIO=0 ENABLE_Ptex=0 ENABLE_Freetype=0 ENABLE_PugiXML=0
```

結果はエラーが出ました。それによって出力された、cmakeのログファイルは以下のリポジトリにアップしてあります。
CMakeError.logとCMakeOutput.logが対象のファイルです。

https://github.com/suikameronn/errorLog

CMakeError.logより

```
error: ‘std::filesystem’ has not been declared
    2 |       int main() { std::filesystem::path p; return 0; }
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

といった記述がありました
std::filesystemのエラーはリポジトリのCMakeError.logに説明のようなものが書かれています。

vcpkgのエラーについて
上のリポジトリのvcpkg_errorというファイルにログをコピペしました。

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:112 (message):
    Command failed: /home/siwameron/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-linux/ninja -v
    Working Directory: /home/siwameron/vcpkg/buildtrees/tiff/x64-linux-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      /home/siwameron/vcpkg/buildtrees/tiff/config-x64-linux-dbg-CMakeCache.txt.log
      /home/siwameron/vcpkg/buildtrees/tiff/config-x64-linux-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      /home/siwameron/vcpkg/buildtrees/tiff/config-x64-linux-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-linux/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_configure.cmake:252 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/tiff/portfile.cmake:30 (vcpkg_cmake_configure)
  scripts/ports.cmake:170 (include)
```

ここが問題なのかもしれません。 ninjaというツールが問題なのでしょうか。
ninja-buildはインストールしてます。

##### 追記2

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17`のようにしましたが、c++17でビルドできませんでした。

```
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_e11e4/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Library/openimageio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DUSE_STD_FILESYSTEM  -std=c++14 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/user/Library/openimageio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/user/Library/openimageio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/user/Library/openimageio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:25: error: ‘std::filesystem’ has not been declared
    2 |       int main() { std::filesystem::path p; return 0; }
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_e11e4.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Library/openimageio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_e11e4/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: [ビルドログ](https://github.com/suikameronn/errorLog/blob/main/CMakeError.log)に出力されている通り`-std=c++14`でコンパイルされているので、C++17で追加された`std::filesystem`は使えません。

Answer (score 1):

[Installing from package managers](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenImageIO/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-from-package-managers)に従ってみてはどうでしょうか。[vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)をインストールした状態であれば

```
vcpkg install openimageio
```

を実行することでインストールできます。
なお、vcpkgはパッケージマネージャではありますが、ビルド済みバイナリをダウンロードするツールではなく、依存する全てのソースコードをダウンロードし、ビルドを行ってくれます。なので「このリポジトリのライブラリをソースコードからビルドしたい」を満たすと思います。

Answer (score -2):

vcpkgを使って、openimageioをインストールするときに、参照している別ドライブであるcドライブのvcpkg/cmake/scriptsないのエラーを起こしているフォルダを削除したら、とりあえずインストールすることはできました。